# I am trying to simulate search value by puppeteer on zap.website without success

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

```
await page.$eval('input[name=search]', el => el.value = 'Adenosine triphosphate');
```

Comment: I am trying to do so on search bar without success

Comment: I have fixed your code block, but unfortunately your question isn't clear at all. Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi I am trying this on www.zap.co.il and it's not working : Any idea what is the issue?

const inputElement = await page.$('input[type=search]'); await page.goto('https://www.zap.co.il', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}); await page.waitFor('input[type=search]');

await page.$eval('input[type=search]', el => el.value = 'HP')

Comment: I am trying to simulate search on www.zap.co.il: by page.waitFor('input[type=search]'); await page.$eval('input[type=search]', el => el.value = 'HP')